# Conditionally hide menu button in ionic framework outside <ion-view>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In the ionic framework I am trying to hide the menu button conditionally. For other reasons I had to split the menu in its own controller (I don't want to completly re-render the menu and header bar on a refresh), so the header is not in ion-view. I created a watcher on the conditional variable (a stateparam) in the controller of the header. The console log outputs the conditional variable correctly, but the view is not updated (the menu button is always showing).

This is the template:

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button ng-if="!isHome" class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i>Back</ion-nav-back-button>
            <button ng-if="isHome" menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>

        </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>

...
</ion-side-menus>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $stateParams.contentUrl;
},
    function(newVal){
        console.log(newVal);
        if(!newVal || newVal === 'someParam'){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.isHome = true;
                });
                console.log("home");
            });
        } else {
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.isHome = false;
                });
                console.log("not home");
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there an easier way? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `hide-back-button` attribute on the `<ion-view>` element to declare if that view should hide the back button by default.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionView/

```
<ion-view hide-back-button="true">
  <!-- view contents -->
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I cannot use the ion-view because that causes the header to get rerendered on state.go :(

Comment: You actually can, ion-view and ion-nav-bar are aware of one another. Put the hide-back-button attribute on any view that you want to hide the back button, and the ion-view will inform the ion-nav-bar to hide the button. Perhaps your example is not clear enough.

Comment: back button is different from side menu button, hide-back-button doesn't work on side menu button

Comment: The question was to hide the side menu button(menuToggle) and not the back button or am I getting wrong?

Comment: @mhanisch I am finding the same issue. have you got any help ?

Comment: In case Jeremies fix above does not work for you as well, you can try my dirty workaround below. Sadly, that is what I was stuck with. Keep in mind though, that this is from an old version of ionic - there might be a better way today.

Answer (score 1):

A kinda dirty workaround would be to give those buttons an id and then use jqlite to hide them like this in the controller:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#back-button')).addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `hide-back-button` to false did not work for me. However, in my case the easier solution was to have

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left"></ion-nav-buttons>
```

inside `<ion-view>`. This is to just include a empty left side nav buttons. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a  easy way:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views = "true">
```

and on the specific pages where you want to hide the Menu and nav bar, let say your Login Page(inside your login Controller), just type- don't forget to include specified objects inside the controller function.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event) {
$scope.$root.showMenuIcon = false;
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function (event) {
  $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = true;
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
});
```